# Unprotect and protect receiving worksheet in another workbook vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks. One of them sends data to the other one and everything has worked fine. However, now I want the receiving workbook's worksheet to be protected and during datatransfer VBA should unprotect and then copy all wanted data to it and finally again protect the receiving worksheet. What am I missing here? I use Worksheet.Unprotect and copy data and then Worksheet.Protect finally to protect the receiving worksheet. I get error 400. My code below, which I execute with a button (Form Control):

```
Sub Datatransfer()

Dim myPath As String 'this workbook path
Dim RecPath As String 'receiving workbook path
Dim RecFile As String 'receiving workbook complete name

RecPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Documents\"
RecFile = "Data_Receive_Test.xlsx"

myPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName


If Dir(RecPath & RecFile) = "" Then

MsgBox "The path to the receiving workbook is missing, please contact your admin!", vbCritical, _
"No access to receiving workbook!"

    Exit Sub

    ElseIf MsgBox("User: " & Environ("Username") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Are you sure you want to copy the information below to the other workbook?" _
                & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "By choosing 'YES' the information below will overwrite the current information in the receiving workbook, which cannot be canceled later on!", _
                vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Warning!") = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'Define both workbooks
Dim x As Workbook 'this workbook
Dim y As Workbook 'receiving workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open(myPath)
Set ws1 = x.Sheets("COMPLETED")

Dim rngCopy As Range

ws1.Range("A5").Select

Set rngCopy = ws1.Range("A5:B300")

rngCopy.Copy

Set y = Workbooks.Open(RecPath & RecFile)
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("TEST SHEET")

ws2.Select
ws2.Range("A5").Select

ws2.Unprotect Password:="TESTPROTECT"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ws2.Range("A5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ws2.Range("A3").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ws2.Protect Password:="TESTPROTECT"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Activate sending workbook (this) just to be sure
x.Activate
ws1.Range("A3").Select
ws1.Range("A3") = "Data transfer in progress..."

MsgBox "Data transfer in progress," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "both workbooks are being saved, please wait!", _
vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Information!"


'Save both workbooks
y.Save
x.Save

'Close receiving workbook
y.Close True

ws1.Range("A3").Select

ws1.Range("A3") = "Data transfer completed!"

x.Save

MsgBox "Data transfer completed," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "both workbooks has been saved!", _
vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Information!"

ws1.Range("A3") = ""
x.Save

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Try removing all the `Range.Select` lines. They don't add anything and might be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you getting error but you should protect workbook only for users, and let VBA work without protect/unprotect. Create Sub and protect your workbook with "UserInterfaceOnly:=True" and forget pain :D.

```
Workbooks("myworkbook.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1").Protect "MyPass", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The problem was actually, that Excel didn't allow to paste in values after unprotecting receiving workbook/sheet. I needed to activate the sending workbook/sheet and copy the data after unprotecting receiving workbook/sheet. Then the copy/paste worked like a charm and I was able to lock the receiving workbook/sheet after the paste was done.

Comment: @Nik_Learning If you will use my example, you wont need anymore protect/unprotect sheet to make sure you can copy->paste data. Your VBA code will always have access to protected sheet without unprotecting it.